# Making a DataGridViewColumn sortable

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, gridview-sorting

I work in C-sharp on ASP NET 4.

I need to add a sorting function to a column in a `GridView`. I've set the `AllowSorting`-property on the `GridView` to `true` and added sort expressions to the column.

Unfortunately, the sorting isn't working in the `GridView`.

Below is my code-behind-file for the column that should be able to sort, but I get the error

> CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataView.DataView(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments

on this line:

```
DataView sortedView = new DataView(BindData());
```

**Code behind:**

```
string sortingDirection;    

public SortDirection dir
{
    get
    {
        if (ViewState["dirState"] == null)
        {
            ViewState["dirState"] = SortDirection.Ascending;
        }
        return (SortDirection)ViewState["dirState"];
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["dirState"] = value;
    }
}

public string SortField
{
    get
    {
        return (string)ViewState["SortField"] ?? "Name";
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["SortField"] = value;
    }
}

protected void gvProducts_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    sortingDirection = string.Empty;
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Descending;
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }
    else
    {
        dir = SortDirection.Ascending;
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }

    DataView sortedView = new DataView(RetrieveProducts());

    sortedView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + sortingDirection;
    SortField = e.SortExpression;
    gvProducts.DataSource = sortedView;
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}

protected void gvProducts_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    if (dir == SortDirection.Ascending)
    {
        sortingDirection = "Asc";
    }
    else
    {
        sortingDirection = "Desc";
    }

    DataView sortedView = new DataView(RetrieveProducts());
    sortedView.Sort = SortField + " " + sortingDirection;
    gvProducts.DataSource = sortedView;
    gvProducts.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}

private void BindData()
{
    gvProducts.DataSource = RetrieveProducts();
    gvProducts.DataBind();
}

private DataSet RetrieveProducts()
{

    DataSet dsProducts = new DataSet();

    string sql = " ... ";

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
      new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnMySQL"].ConnectionString))
    {
        cn.Open();

        using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
              ........
        }
    }

    return dsProducts;
}
```

**Edit #1**

```
DataView sortedView = new DataView(dsProducts.Tables[0]);
```

**Edit # 2**

I have added in aspx page:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name" />
```

But If clicked in **Column Name** I have this new error:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.
```

on this line:

```
Line 100:        DataView sortedView = new DataView(dsProducts.Tables[0]);
```

Comment: But BindData() method returns? You should Give a DataTable ID here... But the BindData() is just a void function...

Comment: @SankarRaj thank you Sir, I have correct please see Edit #1 in my first question; I don't have error but the sorting isn't working in the GridView.

Comment: Did you give 'Onsorting="gvProducts_Sorting"' to your gridview tag

Comment: @SankarRaj Yes Sir ...

Comment: @SankarRaj Please see Edit # 2 in my first question

Comment: **System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.** Sounds there is no datatable in the dataset... Make sure that backend query(which is run while sorting) will return the rows...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84551/discussion-between-sankar-raj-and-antonio-mailtraq).

Comment: @SankarRaj thank you, I need add the datatable in dataset?

Comment: @SankarRaj thank you but my problem is the DataSet

Answer (score 3):

The DataView class has only three constructors, in which one is default constructor DataView(), second one takes a DataTable as an argument DataView(DataTable), the other one takes four arguments DataView(DataTable, String, String, DataViewRowState).

The DataView constructor expects arguments of any one of these types, but your code has argument of some other type. That's the error.

Your BindData method should return a DataTable object,

```
//This function should return a Datatable
    private void BindData()
    {
        gvProducts.DataSource = RetrieveProducts();
        gvProducts.DataBind();
    }
```

which you can pass into your DataView here.

```
DataView sortedView = new DataView(BindData());
```

**For your second edit,**

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 0.
```

on this line:

```
Line 100:        DataView sortedView = new DataView(dsProducts.Tables[0]);
```

I guess the dataset is empty, the error clearly states that there isn't any table in the dataset at position 0. So check whether your dataset has tables or not. Might be your sql request didn't get any table to fill in the dataset.
Else you might have created a new instance of the dataset.

Comment: Thank you Sir, so it is not enough for passed DataTable into dataView? DataView sortedView = new DataView(dsProducts.Tables[0]);

Comment: I have this error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataView.DataView(System.Data.DataTable)' has some invalid arguments with DataView sortedView = new DataView(BindData());